# Error when importing pandas "ImportError: Can't determine version for numexpr"

Tags: python, pandas, import, python-import, importerror

I am having problems with importing the `pandas` package. I used the following command to import it:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  Cell In[54], line 1
    import pandas as pd

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:48
    from pandas.core.api import (

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py:27
    from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py:1
    from pandas.core.arrays.arrow import ArrowExtensionArray

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\arrow\__init__.py:1
    from pandas.core.arrays.arrow.array import ArrowExtensionArray

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\arrow\array.py:60
    from pandas.core.arraylike import OpsMixin

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:21
    from pandas.core.ops.common import unpack_zerodim_and_defer

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py:38
    from pandas.core.ops.array_ops import (

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:57
    from pandas.core.computation import expressions

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py:20
    from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\check.py:5
    ne = import_optional_dependency("numexpr", errors="warn")

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:157 in import_optional_dependency
    version = get_version(module_to_get)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:84 in get_version
    raise ImportError(f"Can't determine version for {module.__name__}")

ImportError: Can't determine version for numexpr
```

I am using the following version of Python:

```
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:39:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Some important information is maybe that this computer has remote access to the server that I'm using via VPN. So I should only have access to the program when I am logged into the VPN.

Comment: Uninstall `numpexpr` (it's probably an older version) then reinstall it. `conda remove numexpr`  then `conda install numexpr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ubuntu linux, you can try `sudo apt-get install python-numexpr`. Refer this answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/446644/why-do-i-get-importerror-when-trying-to-import-pandas-python-module

After installing numexpr and bottleneck, you can try `pip install --force-reinstall pandas` or `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas` to ensure pandas is installed properly.

Comment: I'm on windows unfortunately.

Comment: try only `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas`

Comment: That gave me an error.   Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.24.3
    Uninstalling numpy-1.24.3:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.24.3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\'username'\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\~libs\\libopenblas64__v0.3.21-gcc_10_3_0.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas --user`. If it does not work, you can try restarting your shell as administrator and run `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas` to gain permissions.

Comment: About three of the packages that gets installed have the warning:  WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\victor\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location. 

PS I'm so sorry this gets dragged out. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: You can ignore the warning. Please accept my answer and upvote if it has solved your issue.

Comment: I posted the warning, because spyder now gives the same error as the one I posted but with another of these three packages that had the warning. But I think you did enough, so I'll mark it.

Comment: if you are working on a server through spyder, then i think you can try to installing `python-numexpr` on remote server. If the server is a linux machine then it should work. can you give more details on server?

Comment: I will try. I don't know what details to give. Honestly don't understand the whole server too much, so I will try and get some help from the company. Thanks for your help!